# How to add android library (xx.jar) to apk in command-line?

Tags: android, command-line, jar

For some reason I can't build apk by Eclipse.

If I need to add external jar file (include *.class, *.properties..), which files (Android.mk, 
AndroidManifest.xml, default.properties?) do I need to modify and how should I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android build apk with javacv.jar & javacpp.jar about JavaCV in command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257843/android-build-apk-with-javacv-jar-javacpp-jar-about-javacv-in-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

For a standard Ant-based build, to include a third-party JAR, make a `libs/` directory in your project and copy the JAR there. Everything else is handled for you by the standard Ant build script.